# Why does these two code pieces give different results

Tags: c++

I was trying to learn about "<" operator on c++ strings and tried some test cases. I realized the two codes which  I thought should behave the same was giving different results. Below are the codes, what is the reason for this?

```
  string s="test";
  string k="tes";
  cout<<(s<k)<<endl; //returns false so it prints 0
  cout<<("test"<"tes")<<endl; // returns true so it prints 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(s < k)` compares the values of the strings as you would expect.

`("test" < "tes")` compares the pointers to the beginning of the string literals as the compiler decides to arrange them in memory. Therefore, this comparison may return 0 or 1 depending on the compiler and settings in use, and both results are correct. The comparison is effectively meaningless.

The "C way" to compare these string literals would be `strcmp("test", "tes")`.

Comment: Then does the string literal "test" does not really refer to a string object? Is it like type casting when I declare string s ="test"; ?

Comment: @OgiciBumKacar Correct, that invokes the `std::string(char const *)` implicit conversion constructor.

Comment: Thank you! This clears a lot

Answer (score 0):

`s` and `k` are `string` objects for which a comparison operator has been defined and performs what you expect.

`"test"` and `"tes"` are pointers to char that hold the address of the locations where these characters are stored. Thus the comparison is on the addresses.